# SugarCRM Enterprise 7.9.2.0 - SugarQuery just won't work. [php]

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sugarcrm

Ok so I'm trying to use SugarQuery for extracting data from SugarCRM in my custom plugin. Sugar is installed locally.
When I use Sugar DbManager I'm able to get data from DB as shown below, my $result contains first_name:

```
$GLOBALS['db'];
$db = DBManagerFactory::getInstance();
$query = 'SELECT first_name FROM contacts WHERE id = ?';
$conn = $GLOBALS['db']->getConnection();
$stmt = $conn->executeQuery($query, array($id));
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

But when I try to use SugarQuery builder:

```
$sugarQuery = new SugarQuery();
$sugarQuery->from(BeanFactory::getBean("Contacts"));
$sugarQuery->select('first_name');
$sugarQuery->where()->contains('id',$id);
$sugarQuery->distinct(true);
$result = $sugarQuery->execute();
```

my result is an empty array, and when I check mysql logs this is the SQL:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT contacts.first_name FROM contacts INNER JOIN (
  SELECT tst.team_set_id
  FROM team_sets_teams tst
  INNER JOIN team_memberships team_memberships
  ON tst.team_id = team_memberships.team_id
    AND team_memberships.user_id = ''
    AND team_memberships.deleted = 0
  GROUP BY tst.team_set_id
) contacts_tf ON contacts_tf.team_set_id = contacts.team_set_id WHERE (contacts.id LIKE '%b8e8d8fe-de50-11e7-8770-1c3947366abf%') AND (contacts.deleted = 0)
```

Tried to run the SQL manually from phpmyadmin and there is no results retrieved from DB. Probably there is a problem with no value for team_memberships.user_id. When I manually enter team_memberships.user_id, then the SQL works and returns first_name.

Any ideas why this team_memberships.user_id is empty, why SugarQuery Builder doesn't set any value for it? I couldn't find anything about it in SugarCrm documentation unfortunately. Maybe there is something wrong with my SugarQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need this query to use team security, then changing

```
$sugarQuery->from(BeanFactory::getBean("Contacts"))
```

to

```
$sugarQuery->from(BeanFactory::getBean("Contacts"), array('team_security' => false));
```

should do the trick.

See https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.9/Data_Framework/Database/SugarQuery/#from

If you do need team security and your code runs in a independent php script (instead of Sugar's Scheduler, LogicHook, API etc.), then maybe the current user isn't loaded and you have to do that manually.

```
global $current_user;
$current_user = new User();
$current_user->getSystemUser();
```

will load the admin user. You may want to adjust that to load the user of your choice.

Comment: Thanks! Changing team_security to false solved my problem!